# jquery event bubbling

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-bubbling

Can someone explain to me why

```
var divdbl = $("div:first");
var i = 0;

divdbl.change(function(){
    alert('change');    
}).click();

divdbl.click(function(){
    i++;
    alert('click '+i);
}).change();
```

behaves like they are calling themselves, even if I do it like this

```
divdbl.click(function(){
    i++;
    alert('click '+i);
}).change();

divdbl.change(function(){
    alert('change');    
}).click();
```

its as if they are calling themselves instead of the other.

**EDIT**

```
var divdbl = $("div:first");
var i = 0;

divdbl.change(function(){
    alert('change');    
});

divdbl.click(function(){
    i++;
    alert('click '+i);
}).change().click();
```

i just realized that what i wanted to accomplish was to force them to run once on load
Would the above code make sense?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What result are you getting and what result are you expecting>

Comment: `divdbl.click(function(){}).click();` calls itself but attaching another event would it not call the other event handler?

Comment: What do you mean by "Itself" in calls itself?

Comment: i defined a click handler and called it within its declaration `divdbl.click(function(){...}).click();`

Comment: Yeah, that's not what the code in your question says. Can you update your question to reflect that?

Comment: just updated the question to clarify it more, sorry i didnt make myself clear about my question

Comment: What does "on load" refer to? When the page loads? Why not just split the guts of those out into a separate function and assign it to the click handler and on a separate line in $(().ready call the function directly. Intermingling them just makes your code hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all, there's an issue because you are calling triggering `change()` handler before it is defined. What are you trying to accomplish? Calling `.change()` and `.click()` runs the functions for those events.

**EDIT:**

Based on your recent update to your question: Yes, that will work as intended. Both .click and .change will be invoked upon load.

Comment: 1. are you referring to the first or second? 2. i'm experimenting to know if you can call another event by appending another event, i.e . event bubbling

Comment: **1.)** In the first, you are calling `.click()` before it exists. In the second, you are calling `.change()` before it exists. **2.)** Ah. What part of the code are you analyzing?

Comment: **1.)** so does that mean that if I issue an event but there is no handler for it, it executes the handler to which it was appended? **2.)** calling `$('#id').click(function(){...}) .click();` will call itself, just thinking if it might be possible if there were two handlers since both were attached to the same DOM element

Comment: **1.)** No, triggering an event will invoke default behavior (if you have no handler for that event defined). It varies. For example, calling `$("#myElement").focus()` will focus an element, unless you define a handler for that `focus()`, which will focus an element *and* call your handler. **2.)** You are correct...

Comment: Yes, that will work as intended. Both `.click` and `.change` will be invoked upon load.

Comment: how do i go about this,in SO. it seems that we are just having a discusion, is this even allowed in SO? or am i supposed to accept your answer?

Comment: I will edit it to reflect my answer to match your update, then you can accept it.